# Как сделать анимацию бегущего прогрессбара?

Tags: android, svg, анимация, svg-animation

У меня есть progressbar на который я хочу повесить анимацию бесконечно бегущей полоски.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я не понимаю, как это реализовать.
В моем `main_activity.xml` у меня есть `progressbar` и `imageview`. которое я буду анимировать.

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/price"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progress_bar"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/animated_image_on_progressbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/animated_veсtor_progressbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/price"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progress_bar"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Также имеется файл progress_bar_animated.xml

```
<vector android:alpha="0.94" android:height="20dp"
android:viewportHeight="1500" android:viewportWidth="10500"
android:width="140dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:name="path_1" android:fillColor="#C5C6C6" android:pathData="M322,172h9787v915h-9787z"/>
<path android:name="path_2" android:fillColor="#898989" android:pathData="M333,1087l684,-915l1378,0l-665,915z"/>
<path android:name="path_3" android:fillColor="#898989" android:pathData="M2853,1087l684,-915l1378,0l-664,915z"/>
<path android:name="path_4" android:fillColor="#898989" android:pathData="M5367,1087l684,-915l1379,0l-665,915z"/>
<path android:name="path_5" android:fillColor="#898989" android:pathData="M7893,1087l684,-915l1379,0l-665,915z"/>
```

animated_vector

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_animated">

<target
    android:name="path_1"
    android:animation="@animator/animate_progressbar" />

<target
    android:name="path_2"
    android:animation="@animator/animate_progressbar" />

<target
    android:name="path_3"
    android:animation="@animator/animate_progressbar" />
<target
    android:name="path_4"
    android:animation="@animator/animate_progressbar" />
<target
    android:name="path_5"
    android:animation="@animator/animate_progressbar" />
```

Я не очень понимаю, каким должен быть аниматор?

А также, как быть с размером, т.к размер менять не так просто в svg файлах, а размер progressbar (20dp and match_parent).

Comment: можно же поставить `android:indeterminate="true"` в прогресс баре и тогда он будет бесконечно бегать

Comment: И я же без проблем смогу сделать кастомную анимацию как на картинке??

Answer (score 4):

Решение на pure SVG. Я думаю, что наверное будет возможно  его перевести в android формат.

Идея заключается в создании прямоугольников, которые наклоняются на нужный угол с помощью команды `transform="skewX(-45)"`

Затем они клонируются `<use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(-150,0)"/>` несколько раз до полного заполнения полоски.

Полоска анимируется с помощью команды

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate"
   dur="2.5s" from="0 0" to="150 0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

*Начало анимации после клика по холсту SVG*

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="40" fill="#3A8582" /> 
   <!-- <rect x="20" y="10" width="560" height="80" fill="#d3d3d3"  /> -->
<defs>
 <g id="bshop"  transform="skewX(-45)">
   <g id="base">
  <rect  y="10" x="0" height="30%" width="40" fill="#DCDCDC"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="40" height="30%" width="35" fill="#7B7B7B"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="75" height="30%" width="40" fill="#DCDCDC"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="115" height="30%" width="35" fill="#7B7B7B"/>
     </g>  
  
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(-150,0)"/>
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(150,0)"/>
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(300,0)"/>
 </g>
 
 <pattern id="barber" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="150" height="30" >
 <use xlink:href="#bshop" transform="translate(0,0)">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click" dur="2.5s" from="0 0" to="150 0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </use>
</pattern>
</defs>

  <rect x="10" y="10" height="30" width="580" rx="5"  fill="url(#barber)"/>

</svg>
```

**Вариант с объемной бегущей полосой**

Для придания объема используется линейный градиент:

```
<linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0" x2="0" y2="0.9">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
    <stop offset="0.3" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    <stop offset="0.4" stop-color="white" stop-opacity=".8"/>
    <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity=".6"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" stop-opacity=".9"/>
</linearGradient>
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="50" fill="#3A8582" /> 
   <!-- <rect x="20" y="10" width="560" height="80" fill="#d3d3d3"  /> -->
<defs>
 <g id="bshop"  transform="skewX(-45)">
   <g id="base">
  <rect  y="10" x="0" height="30%" width="40" fill="#DCDCDC"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="40" height="30%" width="35" fill="#7B7B7B"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="75" height="30%" width="40" fill="#DCDCDC"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="115" height="30%" width="35" fill="#7B7B7B"/>
   </g>  
   
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(-150,0)"/>
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(150,0)"/>
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(300,0)"/>
  
    </g>
 
 <pattern id="barber" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="150" height="30" >
 <use xlink:href="#bshop" transform="translate(0,0)">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="2.5s" from="0 0" to="150 0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </use>
</pattern>
</defs>

  <rect x="10" y="10" height="30" width="580" rx="5"  fill="url(#barber)"/>
 
 <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0" x2="0" y2="0.9">
 <stop offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
 <stop offset="0.3" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
 <stop offset="0.4" stop-color="white" stop-opacity=".8"/>
 <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity=".6"/>
 <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" stop-opacity=".9"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect x="10" y="10" width="580" height="30" rx="5" fill="url(#gradient1)"/>
</svg>
```

**Вариант со счётчиком**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="50" fill="#3A8582" /> 
   <!-- <rect x="20" y="10" width="560" height="80" fill="#d3d3d3"  /> -->
<defs>
 <g id="bshop"  transform="skewX(-45)">
   <g id="base">
  <rect  y="10" x="0" height="30%" width="40" fill="#DCDCDC"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="40" height="30%" width="35" fill="#7B7B7B"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="75" height="30%" width="40" fill="#DCDCDC"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="115" height="30%" width="35" fill="#7B7B7B"/>
   </g>  
   
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(-150,0)"/>
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(150,0)"/>
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(300,0)"/>
  
    </g>
 
 <pattern id="barber" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="150" height="30" >
 <use xlink:href="#bshop" transform="translate(0,0)">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="2.5s" from="0 0" to="150 0" repeatCount="4"/>
 </use>
</pattern>
</defs>

  <rect x="10" y="10" height="30" width="580" rx="5"  fill="url(#barber)"/>
 
 <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0" x2="0" y2="0.9">
 <stop offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
 <stop offset="0.3" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
 <stop offset="0.4" stop-color="white" stop-opacity=".8"/>
 <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity=".6"/>
 <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" stop-opacity=".9"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect x="10" y="10" width="580" height="30" rx="5" fill="url(#gradient1)"/>
                   <!-- Проценты   -->
  <rect x="250" y="16" height="16" width="40" rx="5"  fill="#DCDCDC" stroke="#7B7B7B" stroke-width="0.6" />
  <text id="count" x="270" y="21" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="14" fill="#111111">100%</text>
</svg> 

<script>
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 10000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});
</script>
```

**Вариант с объемной цветной бегущей полосой**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="50" fill="#3A8582" /> 
   
<defs>
 <g id="bshop"  transform="skewX(-45)">
   <g id="base">
  <rect  y="10" x="0" height="30%" width="40" fill="#e12"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="40" height="30%" width="35" fill="#ddd"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="75" height="30%" width="40" fill="#11c"/>
  <rect  y="10" x="115" height="30%" width="35" fill="#ddd"/> 
   
   </g>  
 
  
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(-150,0)"/>
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(150,0)"/>
 <use xlink:href="#base" transform="translate(300,0)"/>
  
    </g>
 
 <pattern id="barber" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="150" height="30" >
 <use xlink:href="#bshop" transform="translate(0,0)">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="2.5s" from="0 0" to="150 0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </use>
</pattern>
</defs>

  <rect x="10" y="10" height="30" width="580" rx="5"  fill="url(#barber)"/>
 
 <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0" x2="0"  y2="1">
 <stop offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
 <stop offset="0.3" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.2"/>
 <stop offset="0.4" stop-color="white" stop-opacity=".9"/>
 <stop offset="0.6" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.6"/>
 <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" stop-opacity=".9"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect x="10" y="5" width="580" height="30" rx="5" fill="url(#gradient1)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: ................))